# Error reading binary file in Visual Studio 19 using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, binaryfiles, ifstream

I tried to read binary files with C++ in Windows10 and Visual Studio 2019, and it is found that the reading result is wrong. The code is as follows:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>

using real = double;

int main()
{
    constexpr int N = 1000;
    std::printf("Matrix size: %d x %d\n", N, N);

    // prepare matrix data
    std::vector<std::vector<real>> matrix(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        matrix[i].resize(N);
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = i * 1.32 + j * 4.23 + 1.42;
        }
    }

    // write to binary file
    std::ofstream binFile("binFile", std::ios::binary);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        binFile.write((char*)(matrix[i].data()), sizeof(real) * N);
    }

    // read from binary file
    std::vector<real> loadFromBinary(N * N);
    std::ifstream binFileID("binFile", std::ios::binary);
    binFileID.read((char*)(loadFromBinary.data()), sizeof(real) * N * N);

    // check for each element
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (loadFromBinary[i * N + j] != matrix[i][j]) {
                std::printf("Not equal: [%d][%d]: %f and %f\n", i, j, loadFromBinary[i * N + j], matrix[i][j]);
                std::exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
    std::printf("All equal\n");
}
```

under Debug or Release and x64 model, the output is as follows:

```
Matrix size: 1000 x 1000
Not equal: [999][936]: 0.000000 and 5279.380000
```

But the result is OK in Linux.

Comment: You didn't close `binFile` before opening the same file again. My guess is, the tail of the data has not been flushed to the file and is still sitting in `binFile`'s internal buffers.

Comment: Thanks, the result is OK when adding `binFile.close()`